# Why I am not able to display image notifications?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a flutter application and displaying notifications with awesome_notifications package (https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications). Below is my code.

```
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: UniqueKey().hashCode,
        groupKey: message.data["senderUid"],
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        title: message.data["title"],
        body: message.data["body"],
        summary: message.data["body"], // Anything you want here
        bigPicture:
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/TEIDE.JPG/2560px-TEIDE.JPG",
        notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Messaging,
      ),
    );
```

This code does not display any notifications. Instead if I remove the `bigPicture`, then it will show the message without the picture.

How can I show the notification image?

Answer (score 0):

Use correct [notificationLayout](https://pub.dev/documentation/awesome_notifications/latest/awesome_notifications/NotificationLayout.html), in this case `BigPicture`.